# How to run flow.InstalledAppFlow run_local_server() from a google cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-shell

I run some CLI python code from the `cloud terminal`.
The code calls "google_auth_oauthlib" library.

```
    auth_flow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file=client_secret_json_file_fath, scopes=scopes)
    auth_flow.run_local_server()
```

I get in the cloud terminal an authentication url to click on.
I pass the consent screen and I'm redirected to a localhost in the browser, which obviously cannot be resolved.

How can I get the secrets from google-cloud terminal?

[image]

Comment: `InstalledAppFlow` runs on the same machine as the web browser. Run the code on your local system and not in Cloud Shell.

Comment: Right, but this is what I was asked. Is it possible to run on a cloud shell?

Comment: This is the third question you have all along the same lines can't you just have one question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is something like this.

```
def build_service(credentials, scope, user_token):
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists(user_token):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(user_token, scope)

    # If there are no (valid) user credentials available, prompt the user to log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                credentials, scope)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(user_token, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    try:
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - any errors returned.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')

# Get an authorized Google Drive service object.
google_api_service = build_service(APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, SCOPES, USER_TOKENS)
```

If you run this code on your machine once.  It will store the refresh token in the user_tokens file. then you can upload it to your cloud server and when it runs it will use that token file.

although it would probably be easer to use a service account if you can.

Comment: Thanks! (1)  `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)` a value is returned despite the redirect uri is not seen on an external (non cloud) browser? (2) how would you write the whole code flow with a service-account?

Comment: Service accounts are completely different and depends on what API you are accessing

Comment: I'll be using YT analytics API, YT Data API, Google-Ads API

Comment: YouTube doesn't support services accounts.    I'm not sure about ads you need to apply for access to that one